# Can't import pmdarima even though it's installed properly

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, python-import, conda

I have a working installation of pmdarima in a conda enviroment

> (pmdarima) > pip list | findstr pmdarima
>
> pmdarima        1.1.0

And when I run python I am able to import pmdarima.

> (pmdarima) > python
>
> Python 3.7.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 20 2019, 01:38:26) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
>
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> >>> from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
>
> >>>

But when I run a python script which imports pmdarima package I get this error.

> (pmdarima) > python pmdarima.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "pmdarima.py", line 4, in
>
> from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
>
> File "project_path\pmdarima.py", line 4, in
>
> from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pmdarima.arima'; 'pmdarima' is not a package

After getting this error I reopen python in the same enviroment and I cant even import the package here anymore

> (pmdarima) > python
>
> Python 3.7.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 20 2019, 01:38:26) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
>
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> >>> from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "project_path\pmdarima.py", line 4, in
>
> from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pmdarima.arima'; 'pmdarima' is not a package

After restarting the terminal I can import the package again in python and the rest repeats itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the name of my file. It was conficting with the name of the library. Thanks for your vote. It realy helped a lot!